# How to create a single thread cooldown

Tags: java, java-threads

I'm finding the way to make a Single thread cooldown but get stuck.
In the class who manages the cooldown I created a:

```
private HashMap<UUID,Integer> players = new HashMap<>();

//UUID = Player UUID
//Integer = Time in cooldown (Seconds)

public void run(){
for(UUID player : players){
    //WHAT I NEED TO DO HERE?
    if(//Time == 0){
      players.remove(player);
      }
   }
}
```

Didn't use an IDE hopefully I didn't miss an error that eclipse would have picked up.

But how I can get the integer and save it with a second less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) is used for delaying a process, as it could be used as followed:

`TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);`

This will delay the current thread by one second.

I **won't suggest using it**, because your situation sounds more like a thread is working in the background and you want to wait till it has finished! Therefore use the new feature [isAlive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29), which could be used in a (`while`) loop.

---

### **Edit**

If you do want to delay a thread from another thread over the instance, then I'd suggest using the [sleep method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)).

Example:

```
myThread.sleep(1000);
```

This will delay `myThread` by one second.

---

### **Edit #2**

To change a value for a certain key of a `HashMap`, use the [put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)) and [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method.

Example:

```
// Get the time of a player and subtract it by one
Integer value = players.get(player) - 1;
// Update the value
players.put(player, value);

// If the time runs out, than delete the player
if (value == 0){
    players.remove(player);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to change the hashmap Integer, do you have an idea to do that?

Comment: Updated the answer.